# $R$ is a commutive ring, and $A, B, C$ are ideals in $R$. If $A + B = A + C$ and $A ∩ B = A ∩ C$, then it is necessary that $B = C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

My question is: $R$ is a commutive ring, and $A, B, C$ are ideals in $R$.  If $A + B = A + C$ and $A ∩ B = A ∩ C$, then it is necessary that $B = C$?

I come up with this question because when $ R $ is P.I.D, $A + B$ is generated by the gcd of the generators of $ A $ and $ B $ and $ A ∩ B $ is generated by the lcm of the generators of $ A $ and $ B $. In this case, the above statement is clearly true. I was wondering whether we need such strong condition (e.g., $ R $ is P.I.D) to make the statement true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't hold in general, though it does hold for arithmetical rings (in particular Prüfer domains), which are more general than PIDs.

For the counterexample, take $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ for a field $k$, and denote by $\delta=x+(x^2,xy,y^2)$ resp. $\varepsilon=y+(x^2,xy,y^2)$ the classes of $x$ resp. $y$ in $R$. Then $1,\delta,\varepsilon$ form a $k$-basis of $R$, and we have the realtions $\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon\delta=\delta^2=0$.

Now take $A=(\delta+\varepsilon)$, $B=(\delta)$ and $C=(\varepsilon)$. Then using the description above, one may verify that $A+B=(\delta,\varepsilon)=A+C$, and $A\cap B=(0)=A\cap C$. However, $B\neq C$.

On the other hand, suppose that $R$ is arithmetical: a common definition for this is that for all ideals $I,J,K$ of $R$ we have $I\cap(J+K)=I\cap J+I\cap K$. Now take ideals $A,B,C$ of $R$ satisfying $A+B=A+C$ and $A\cap B=A\cap C$. In particular, we have $A\cap (B+C)=A\cap B+A\cap C=A\cap B=A\cap C$.

Now take any element $b\in B$. Then $b\in A+C$, so there exist $a\in A$ and $c\in C$ such that $b=a+c$. Thus $b-c\in A\cap (B+C)=A\cap C$ by the above argument, and hence also $b\in C$. So we proved $B\subseteq C$, and by symmetry we obtain $B=C$.

It would be interesting to know whether the condition
$$
\forall\text{ ideals }A,B,C\subseteq R:\left((A+B=A+C)\ \land\ (A\cap B=A\cap C)\right)\implies B=C
$$
implies the condition
$$
\forall\text{ ideals }I,J,K\subseteq R: I\cap(J+K)=I\cap J+I\cap K,
$$
but intuitively I don't think this is the case.

Edit: This last question is settled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620593/are-rings-where-for-all-ideals-leftab-ac-land-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-right) by Jacob Manaker: contrary to what I expected, the only rings where $A+B=A+C$ and $A\cap B=A\cap C$ always implies $B=C$ are precisely the arithmetical rings.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. Didn't you prove the statement for Prüfer domains?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes you are right of course, I edited my answer accordingly. I meant to say that I wonder whether Prüfer domains (or rather arithmetical rings because the assumption of domain is redundant in this context) are the only cases where this works. That is, is it true that if the statement in question holds for all ideals, then $R$ is arithmetical? I ask this here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620593/are-rings-where-leftab-ac-land-a-cap-b-a-cap-c-right-implies-b-c-a