# Are rings where for all ideals $\left((A+B=A+C)\ \land\ (A\cap B=A\cap C)\right)\implies B=C$ automatically arithmetical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Inspired by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620157/r-is-a-commutive-ring-and-a-b-c-are-ideals-in-r-if-a-b-a-c-and), I wonder if the following is true:
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, satisfying the condition
$$
\forall\text{ ideals }A,B,C\subseteq R:\left((A+B=A+C)\ \land\ (A\cap B=A\cap C)\right)\implies B=C.
$$
Does it then also hold that
$$
\forall\text{ ideals }I,J,K\subseteq R: I\cap(J+K)=I\cap J+I\cap K,
$$
i.e. is $R$ arithmetical? Note that the converse is true, as shown in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the only such rings are arithmetical.  This is a good exercise in unraveling lattice-theoretic definitions.

Let $L$ be the lattice of ideals of $R$; just from unraveling the definitions, $R$ is arithmetical iff $L$ is distributive.  A lattice is distributive iff it contains neither $N_5$ nor $M_3$ as sublattices.  If $N_5\nsubseteq L$, then we call $L$ "modular"; every lattice of ring ideals is modular, a fact due to Dedekind and the motivation for the definition of a modular lattice.  Thus it suffices to show $M_3\nsubseteq L$.

But the latter is precisely what your first proposition claims.  For: suppose $\epsilon\subseteq X,Y,Z\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ is a copy of $M_3$ in $L$.  Then $X+Y=\mathfrak{m}=X+Z$ and $X\cap Y=\epsilon=X\cap Z$, so that $Y=Z$, contrary to construction.